# Hide parent activity bottom navigation from fragment not working

Tags: android

I have a fragment loaded on the parent activity. That activity has Bottom Navigation view. I want to hide the Bottom Navigation on certain stage.

Here is what I have tried to do but not working and giving the following error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException:

***If I call those methods on the Activity itself `onCreate(`) it is working fine. Its hiding navigation view.***

### Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="411dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frame_layout"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

### MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    BottomNavigationView navigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        loadFragment(new LiveVideoOneFragment());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.navigation_live_one:
                fragment = new LiveVideoOneFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_live_two:
                fragment = new LiveVideoTwoFragment();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_contact:
                fragment = new ContactFragment();
                break;
        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        if (fragment != null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
                    .commit();

            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public void hideBottomNavigation() {

        if (navigation.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            navigation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    public void showBottomNavigation() {
        if (navigation.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            navigation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

### Fragment

```
...

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        parentActivity.hideBottomNavigation();


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        parentActivity.showBottomNavigation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evidently `parentActivity` is `null`, so where are you assigning it? Your Fragment/Activity interaction should ideally take place via the techniques outlined in the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) via an `interface` anyway.

Comment: Do you mean that I should create an interface within the fragment and implement on the parent activity?

Comment: Yes, following the techiques outlined in the official documentation. You may still need to perform a `null` check before calling your listener however, as I'm not entirely clear on where `onConigurationChanged()` sits in the `Fragment` lifecycle, and it may or may not be called before `onAttachFragment()` (which would mean your interface wouldn't have been assigned so you'll once again get an NPE).

Comment: Well, it's a streaming video so I am trying to make it full-screen when user change the orientation to landscape.